# Google Sheets Array/If Then

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets

I need to create a new tab in Google sheets that will look at the table below and only return a row if there is a non-zero value in a particular column.  For example, on the US tab, there would only be two rows, row 3 and row 6, and it would only include the US column.  New data is added to/changed on the source sheet daily so it would need to update automatically.  Is this possible, and if so, how?

```
Date    Description Amount  US     Mexico   Canada  Japan
05/10/21    blue    208.80           2.00       
05/06/21    green   220.00  220.00          
05/04/21    brown   131.00              
05/03/21    black   75.00            22.00      
05/06/21    gray    20.00   30.00             27.00 
05/06/21    orange  82.00               
05/06/21    red    110.00                            23.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `QUERY` function.

As per my screengrab below, here is an example to go in row `I1`:

`=query({A:G},"select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col4 >0 order by Col1,Col2 label Col3 'US Amount'",1)`

I've put the range `A:G` inside `{}` so that I can use the Col1,Col2,Col3 notation rather than A,B,C - helpful if the columns of data might move somewhere else in the sheet and not start in Col A.

`QUERY` is a pseudo SQL and very powerful.

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en-GB

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#language-clauses

[image]